# Why I am getting an error as "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot add property bookId, object is not extensible" into my redux-slice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, redux-toolkit

I am fetching 2 types of resources from the json-server named , toys, and books.
So I made some seed data to both of the respective resources, and made the respective type files as well.
I have a common search bar. Which is meant to search toys and books together, whether there is a match or not?
Since, end users would be posting a toy or a book with no particular sequence. So, I assigned a uuid() - from react-uuid as selectId (property inside either of createEntityAdapter for toys, or books).

Please acknowledge my code below -
my toySlice.ts file

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createEntityAdapter, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import uuid from "react-uuid";
import agent from "../../../../api/agent";
import { Toy } from "../../../../models/Toy";
import { RootState } from "../../../Redux/reduxStore";

interface JobState {
    status : string,
    loadedToys : boolean;
    searchTerm : string;
}

export const toysAdaptor = createEntityAdapter<Toy>({
    selectId : ( element ) => element.toyId = uuid() // when toyId is primary key - please focus here
});

// fetching list of toys
export const fetchToysAsync = createAsyncThunk<Job[], string>(
    'jobs/fetchToysAsync',
    async ( searchQuery, thunkAPI ) => {
     try {
        console.log(searchQuery, 'this reached thunk')
       return await agent.TOy.getToys(searchQuery);
        
     } catch ( error : any ) {
     return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({ error : error.data });
     }}
);

export const toySlice = createSlice({
    name : 'toys',
    initialState : toysAdapter.getInitialState<ToyState>({
    status : 'idle',
    loadedToys : false,
    searchTerm : ''
    }),
    reducers : {
      setSearchTerm : ( state, action ) => {
        state.searchTerm = action.payload;
      },
    },
    extraReducers : (builder => {
        builder.addCase(fetchToysAsync.pending, ( state ) => {
            state.status = 'pending'
        });
        builder.addCase(fetchToysAsync.fulfilled, ( state, action ) => {
            jobsAdapter.setAll( state, action );
            state.loadedToys = true;
            state.status = 'idle'
        });
        builder.addCase(fetchToysAsync.rejected, ( state ) => {
            state.status = 'idle'
        });
    })
});

export const toySelector = toysAdapter.getSelectors((state : RootState ) => state.toys );
export const { setSearchTerm } = toySlice.actions;
```

Similary, my bookSlice is as follows -

```
 import { createAsyncThunk, createEntityAdapter, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    import uuid from "react-uuid";
    import agent from "../../../../api/agent";
    import { Book } from "../../../../models/Book";
    import { RootState } from "../../../Redux/reduxStore";
    
    interface BookState {
        status : string,
        loadedBooks : boolean;
        searchTerm : string;
    }
    
    export const bookAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Book>({
        selectId : ( element ) => element.bookId = uuid() // I am having error while setting the selectId to bookId -  please focus here
    });
    
    // fetching list of toys
    export const fetchBooksAsync = createAsyncThunk<Book[], string>(
        'jobs/fetchBooksAsync',
        async ( searchQuery, thunkAPI ) => {
         try {
            console.log(searchQuery, 'this reached thunk')
           return await agent.TOy.getToys(searchQuery);
            
         } catch ( error : any ) {
         return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({ error : error.data });
         }}
    );
    
    export const toySlice = createSlice({
        name : 'books',
        initialState : booksAdapter.getInitialState<BookState>({
        status : 'idle',
        loadedBooks : false,
        searchTerm : ''
        }),
        reducers : {
          setSearchTerm : ( state, action ) => {
            state.searchTerm = action.payload;
          },
        },
        extraReducers : (builder => {
            builder.addCase(fetchBooksAsync.pending, ( state ) => {
                state.status = 'pending'
            });
            builder.addCase(fetchBooksAsync.fulfilled, ( state, action ) => {
                jobsAdapter.setAll( state, action );
                state.loadedBooks = true;
                state.status = 'idle'
            });
            builder.addCase(fetchBooksAsync.rejected, ( state ) => {
                state.status = 'idle'
            });
        })
    });
    
    export const bookSelector = toysAdapter.getSelectors((state : RootState ) => state.books );
    export const { setSearchTerm } = bookSlice.actions;
```

My error is -

```
bookSlice.ts:14 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot add property bookId, object is not extensible
    at selectId (bookSlice.ts:14:1)
    at selectIdValue (utils.ts:4:1)
    at addOneMutably (unsorted_state_adapter.ts:24:1)
    at addManyMutably (unsorted_state_adapter.ts:41:1)
    at setAllMutably (unsorted_state_adapter.ts:72:1)
    at runMutator (state_adapter.ts:36:1)
    at Object.operation [as setAll] (state_adapter.ts:46:1)
    at bookSlice.ts:46:1
    at createReducer.ts:294:1
    at produce (immerClass.ts:94:1)
```

Why I am receiving this error?
Should I make only a single modal for both toys and books? say "post"... I am asking this because, I have only a single search bar which is meant to filter out both, the toys list and the books list, and their data shape hardly have similar properties inside of them.
or should I go with two modals, here in above slices, I have 2 modals as you could see

```
Toy and Book
```

Please suggest me, how could I remove this error to get my data back into the browser window? is this an optimal way of fetching different modals which are meant to be filtered, searched by only single search bar?

All suggestions and corrections are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use the spred operator

```
    selectId : ( element ) => {... element, bookId: uuid()} /
```

Comment: Hllo Sachila , I tried replacing my `selectId : (element) => element.bookId`, with `selectId : (element) => { ...element, bookId : uuid()}`, since you are correct, as I have to make a copy of object to get a workaround this. Still, I am receiving the error as `Type '{ bookId: string; author: string; pages: number; }' is not assignable to type 'EntityId`. I couldn't assign the object to an EntityId

Comment: where did you define `EntityId`

Comment: I haven't defined EntityId anywhere. I just made a type for for Toys and Books, as below  `export interface Toys { toyId : string; name : string}` and `export interface Book {bookId : string; autor : string}` . And I create 2 seperate createEntityAdaptors for each of these inside of my two respective slices. Previously when I made toySlice and passed selectId as `selectId : (el) => el.toyId = uuid()`, my toys were fetching correctly. But, now i made an another slice name bookSlice, and passed `selectId : (el) => el.bookId = uuid()` I am getting error as `typeError : object is not extensible` .

Comment: `Cannot add property bookId, object is not extensible` error to be specific at my selectId statement into my \bookSlice